# Array + Curve modifier with irregular Spacing

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm currently working on a rollercoaster track generated from vendor data. I imported the curve with a python script and I'm placing the track elements on it with two objects, one for the tubes and one for the ties. Those elements are then array and curve modified.
[image]
On my curve (which comes from the original track data), each point represents the position of a track tie.
What I need to achieve is to place the ties on the points of the curve, which have non-regular spacing between each points.
Is there a way I can achieve that automatically (or at least without having to move them all by hand) ?
Thanks.

**Edit:** I also need my ties to stay perpendicular to the curve tilt, which also comes from my initial data-set :
[image]

My track tubes are set-up with simples array+spline modifiers and they automatically fit that tilt :
[image]

**Edit 2** : Here's a simplified .blend file.
https://we.tl/t-6x8JN5OjzX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with geometry nodes like this:

[image]

> Note: For your case you won't need the resample curve node. The geometry nodes modifier is added to the curve in my example.

update:

if you want to "align" the rotation of instanced objects to the curve you can use this node setup:

[image]

** UPDATE **

try this setup here:

[image]

result:

[image]

I know, in the beginning/end, there is some weird rotation. But this might be caused by your curve...so you should check your curve data.

Comment: This will need a bit of tweaking (rotation) but it works ! Many thanks :) Is there a way to apply the curve tilt to the ties too ?

Comment: i updated my answer. If it helped you, please click the checkmark left to my answer. thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, however it isn't able to match the curve's "tilt" (each Spline point has a p.tilt property which I can inspect in edit mode by pressing n) property with that setup. I updated my initial post with a screenshot of what I'm talking about

Comment: Can u provide blend file so we can try out?

Comment: Just updated my initial answer with it.

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: "in the beginning/end, there is some weird rotation." yeah that's the issue I'm encountering too, and it's certainly not from the curve data as the tubes are following the exact same curve. I've plotted my datas on excel and they're really smooth and coherent. I'll have to dig a bit more into this. Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: Also just noticed there's a *Curve tilt* node. Seems to get closer, maybe now I just need to tweak the *Align Euler To Vector* node and hopefully it will be good !